# Error when using GetPwrCapabilities

Tags: c++, winapi, processor

I am trying to run the following code to read the max processor throttle:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Powerbase.h>
#include <PowrProf.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES sysc;

    while (GetPwrCapabilities(&sysc)) {
        cout << " Your Max Throttle is: " << static_cast<double>    (sysc.ProcessorMaxThrottle) << endl;
    }

    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

However , I am receiving the following error:

> `...error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetPwrCapabilities@4 referenced in function _main
>   ...fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`

I tried the solution related to make sure the linker set to console program but it does not work. Any suggestion ?
I am using MSVS 2013.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work, you need to add `PowrProf.lib` to your project setting:

```
Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies
```